# OpenGL ориентация

Tags: java, opengl

Каким образом можно сделать чтобы точка 0, 0 не была в низу слева, а чтобы она была вверху слева?  Пробовал `glOrtho(0D, 640D, 480D, 0D, 0D, 0D)`, но он ничего не делает.

Comment: Ничего не делает, значит? Можете показать полный код? Еще, по умолчанию 0,0 должна быть в центре экрана, а не слева-снизу...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat *"по умолчанию 0,0 должна быть в центре экрана"* - вовсе нет, особенно для `glOrtho`.

Comment: с такими передаваемыми параметрами (0, 0) у вас как раз находится слева, сверху...но меня терзают сомнения что у вас вобще ничего не рисуется, так ли это ?